# Getting a jvm.dll error when installing a program that requires java runtime environment 1.4.1

Tags: java, dll, jvm, installation, jgraph

I am trying to install this program I found called [JGraph](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Office-tools/Other-Office-Tools/JGraphpad.shtml).
Softpedia says the program requires [Java Runtime Environment 1.4.1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase14-419411.html#7019-j2re-1.4.1-oth-JPR).
I had previously updated my version of java, then I installed this older 1.4.1 version of Java runtime environment. 
After that I tried to run the JGraph installer, but I got this error that said:

"Can't launch executable. Could not load jmv.dll. Try re-installing Java VM or change the Java VM used by the application."

I reinstalled Java Runtime 1.4.1 and got the same result. I looked and found jvm.dll in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\j2re1.4.1\bin\client. So I'm not missing the jvm.dll file. But for some reason the installer can't find it when it runs and keeps giving me this error.

I found someone was having a similar problem with MyEclipse. But I can't use that solution since this is an older program I can only locate the setup file.

I am running windows 7 64-bit.

How do I get this program to install if it is possible?

Comment: Most likely it is finding the newer version.  Try running `java -version` from your `CMD`

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure how to tell the computer how to do that. So what exact command would I use to tell it to run the 1.4.1 version?
Also will this cause problems with programs that use the newer version of javascript?

Comment: You can try setting the PATH to use the version of Java you want and start the installer from there.  You don't need to worry about Javascript as this is an unrelated language.  It won't cause a problem with programs which need a newer version of Java until you run them from the same shell.

Comment: Whoops. Yeah I meant to say Java. I've been taking a javascript class so that word is stuck in my head at the moment. But I'll try that out.